# ArcGIS C# RubberPoint.TrackExisting not working

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#

I have a simple marker symbol I have drawn on the map. I am trying to use a rubber band to drag-move it to a new location. I think I am close because when I use .TrackNew instead of .TrackExisting the object with move a little on the screen.

The simple marker symbol:

```
    public void DrawControlPoint(Point3D screenPoint, ISpatialReference mapSpatialReference)
    {
        IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = ((IActiveView)MapController.Map).ScreenDisplay;
        IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = GetGraphicsContainer();
        if (graphicsContainer != null)
        {
            IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation = screenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;
            IPoint mapPoint = displayTransformation.ToMapPoint(screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y);
            mapPoint.Z = screenPoint.Z;
            mapPoint.SpatialReference = mapSpatialReference;

            ISimpleMarkerSymbol simpleMarkerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbolClass();
            simpleMarkerSymbol.Color = EsriConversionUtility.ConvertToRgbColor(Colors.Blue);
            simpleMarkerSymbol.Outline = true;
            simpleMarkerSymbol.OutlineColor = EsriConversionUtility.ConvertToRgbColor(Colors.Red);
            simpleMarkerSymbol.Size = 9;
            simpleMarkerSymbol.Style = esriSimpleMarkerStyle.esriSMSDiamond;

            IMarkerElement markerElement = new MarkerElementClass();
            markerElement.Symbol = simpleMarkerSymbol;                
            var element = (IElement)markerElement;
            element.Geometry = mapPoint;
            IElement elementToAdd = element;
            graphicsContainer.AddElement(elementToAdd, 0);
            MapController.PartialRefreshMap();
            if (ActiveMap.Instance.IsInitialized)
            {
                ActiveMap.Instance.Map.IsDirty = true;
            }                
        }
    }
```

The drag move code:

```
    public void DragMoveControlPoint()
    {
        IElement element = _selectedElement;
        IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = ((IActiveView)MapController.Map).ScreenDisplay;
        IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = GetGraphicsContainer();
        if (graphicsContainer != null)
        {
            IPoint point = element.Geometry as IPoint;
            IGeometry geometry = point;

            screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.hDC, (Int16)esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache);
            IGeometry newGeometry = geometry;
            var rubberBand = new RubberPoint();
            //newGeometrym = rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay, null);
            bool ok = rubberBand.TrackExisting(screenDisplay, null, newGeometry);
            screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();

            graphicsContainer.DeleteElement(element);
            element.Geometry = newGeometry;
            graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);

            MapController.PartialRefreshMap();
            if (ActiveMap.Instance.IsInitialized)
            {
                ActiveMap.Instance.Map.IsDirty = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case I would draw the marker directly, in the OnMouseMove event, to the screen instead of persisting as a geometry object; you're doing a lot of creating and deleting that can be avoided by just drawing directly using IDisplay.DrawPoint http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000v2000000 between IDisplay start/stop drawing phases called by a partial refresh http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000001nm000000 (esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics and use traversed extent) in the OnMouseMove().

Comment: For more info please see a previous answer to a similar question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293034/playing-with-events-of-basetool-to-draw-geometries-in-arcgis-using-arcobjects-c/294292#294292 which should expand on my comment.